# Will a forked version of my repository become the parent repository if I delete it?

Tags: git, github

I have a public repository on GitHub which has been forked by 1 user. I want to delete the repository because of some sensitive data in a commit. If I just delete my repository, will the forked version become the new 'parent' repository and remain there?

[GitHub Help](https://help.github.com/articles/what-happens-to-forks-when-a-repository-is-deleted-or-changes-visibility/) implies that would be the case, but how will the fact it's the new 'parent' repository be displayed?

Answer (score 1):

If you delete your repository, the fork will remain. The proper fix would be to make the sensitive data not relevant anymore by changing credentials or whatever you leaked.

Comment: Thanks, however the sensitive data is names that can't exactly be changed.